# SDL Tridion how to publish pdf file in Tridion to a specific folder on the web site

Tags: tridion

Is there a way to publish pdf or any other binary files to a specific folders on the website, similar to file system structure? Part of my site is used for document repository and I need content manager an ability to simply upload/deploy documents

Comment: could you please post this question at tridion.stackexchange.com? It's the place to be if you need Tridion support...

Comment: moved to tridion.stackexchange.com, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can publish PDFs to a folder (or folders). You can then reference that PDF on webpages. You can link to this PDF as a component similarly to how you link to other webpages as components.